# How to download a page with javascript content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website www.website.com. A web user opens website.come/article.html where there is html text, images.... and javascript content (wich is different for every user).

Now my website is wordpress powered, how can i download the final version (javascript loaded and executed) of the pages opened by my users?

I want to do that because i want to know what content javascript displays for each one of them.

Can i use a php/javascript function or is there any service which do that?

Comment: You could use AJAX to post `document.body.innerHTML` back to the server, if you *really* want to...

Comment: @Kolink +1d but more likely would want `document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: The Kolink's solution with the Paul's suggestion is the right answer for my need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to visit the page, let the javascript run and then extract the content.

There is a PHP bridge available at https://github.com/diggin/php-PhantomjsRunner, but I don't know whether it's any good.

Comment: This solution it's not ok for my question because i need to extract what a user see when javascript runs and not what i see.